# Dynamics CRM Outgoing Email Router

Tags: email, exchange-2010, crm, microsoft-dynamics-crm

Using: Exchange 2010 on Win 2008 & CRM 2011 on Win 2008

I have my email router configured and when I choose test access I get a successful message for Outgoing mail. However, when I reply to an email in the appropriate CRM queue the mail never gets delivered. I check my Exchange logs and it shows no record of having received the mail. Not sure how to proceed from here, how should I troubleshoot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for the error in the event viewer (source Log Name: MSCRMEmail)